# React Formik setFieldValue of other key value within same object

Tags: reactjs, json, formik

My goal is to have an `option select` value selected, once the `onChange` happens it should set 2 `Fields` `values` with `setFieldValue` that have key value pairs within the same object.

My question: How come when I call `setFieldValue('meta', value.meta)` it's not returning the value of the key `meta` and same with `setFieldValue('description', value.description)`?

What I'm not understanding and doing incorrectly: the scope of the `value`.  If the `value` of `id` had a subset of objects I could use the `.description` and `.meta` but it's within the same object.  How can I access this correctly?

Examples I've used: [Formik Select with Other Option](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-select-with-other-option-r6y7w) and [Country and Regions](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-3jfxh?from-embed)

My json:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "created": "July 27, 2021, 10:21 PM",
      "modified": "August 12, 2021, 09:00 PM",
      "name": "Enter the Dragon",
      "description": "One of the greatest Kung Fu movies on my list.",
      "meta": {
        "director": "Robert Clouse",
        "studio": "Warner Bros",
      },
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "created": "July 27, 2021, 10:22 PM",
      "modified": "August 12, 2021, 09:01 PM",
      "name": "Iron Monkey",
      "description": "Another Kung Fu favorite.",
      "meta": {
        "director": "Yuen Wo Ping",
        "studio": "Warner Bros",
      },
    },
}
```

My useEffect and JSX:

```
const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMovieList = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(`/movies/`);
        setMovieList(data.results);
        // console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    getMovieList();
  }, [fetchContext]);

  const initialValues = {
    collection_name: '',
    movies: [
      {
        name: '',
        order: '',
        label: '',
        meta: '',
        description: '',
      },
    ],
  };



<Formik initialValues={initialValues}>
          {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue, handleChange }) => (
            <Form>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name">COLLECTION NAME</label>
                    <Field className="form-control" name="collection_name" type="text" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <h3 className="pt-3">CREATE NEW COLLECTION</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <FieldArray name="movies">
                {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                  <>
                    {values.movies.length > 0 &&
                      values.movies.map((index) => (
                        <div className="row" key={index}>
                          <div className="col-11">
                            <div className="row">
                              <div className="col">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                  <label
                                    htmlFor={`movies.${index}.name`}
                                  >
                                    NAME
                                  </label>
                                  <Field
                                    className="form-control"
                                    as="select"
                                    name={`movies.${index}.name`}
                                    onChange={(event) => {
                                      handleChange(event);
                                      const { value } = event.target;

                                      setFieldValue(`movies.${index}.meta`, value.meta);
                                      setFieldValue(`movies.${index}.description`, value.description);
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <option defaultValue>...</option>
                                    {movieList &&
                                      movieList.map((i) => (
                                        <option key={i.id} value={i.id}>
                                          {i.name}
                                        </option>
                                      ))}
                                  </Field>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                  <label
                                    htmlFor={`movies.${index}.order`}
                                  >
                                    ORDER
                                  </label>
                                  <Field
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name={`movies.${index}.order`}
                                    type="text"
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                  <label
                                    htmlFor={`movies.${index}.label`}
                                  >
                                    LABEL
                                  </label>
                                  <Field
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name={`movies.${index}.label`}
                                    type="text"
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                              <div className="form-group">
                                <label
                                  htmlFor={`movies.${index}.meta`}
                                >
                                  META DATA
                                </label>
                                <textarea
                                    value={values.meta}
                                    id="options"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name={`movies.${index}.meta`}
                                    type="textarea"
                                    rows="4"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                              <div className="form-group">
                                <label
                                  htmlFor={`movies.${index}.description`}
                                >
                                  DESCRIPTION
                                </label>
                                <textarea
                                    value={values.description}
                                    id="options"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name={`movies.${index}.description`}
                                    type="textarea"
                                    rows="4"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-1">
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="btn"
                              onClick={() => remove(index)}
                            >
                              Delete
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn"
                      onClick={() => push({ step: '', label: '' })}
                    >
                      Add Movie Fields
                    </button>
                  </>
                )}
              </FieldArray>
              <div className="my-3">
                <div className="border-bottom" />
              </div>
              <button
                className="btn primary_btn float-right mb-5"
                type="submit"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
              >
                SUBMIT
              </button>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

If this has already been answered please refer me to the correctly answered question.

Comment: The question is not clear . can you please explain a bit more ? where are you facing the issues ? .  Also if possible can you create a code sandbox reproducing your usecase .

Comment: @Shyam updated the question and it focuses on `setFieldValue`

Comment: There is no field value named `meta` so `setFieldValue('meta', value.meta)` will never work  - in your initial values `meta` is a key in an object which is in the array `movies`

Comment: @StudioTime right under the Field for Label is Meta Data with `meta` included.  Please read more carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `map` method is the item in the array not the index . so you need to change it to

```
values.movies.map((movie, index) => (
```

Instead of passing the `meta` and `description` to your setFieldValue you need to pass

```
<Field
  className="form-control"
  as="select"
  name={`movies.${index}.name`}
  onChange={(event) => {
    handleChange(event);
    // find the selected movie from the movie list 
    const selectedMovie = movieList.find(movie => movie.id === event.target.value);

    setFieldValue(`movies.${index}.meta`, selectedMovie.meta);
    setFieldValue(`movies.${index}.description`, selectedMovie.description);
  }}
>
  <option defaultValue>...</option>
  {movieList &&
    movieList.map((i) => (
      <option key={i.id} value={i.id}>
        {i.name}
      </option>
    ))}
</Field>;
```

Comment: I added in the `${index}` but the fields stayed blank and didn't render any of the `meta` or `description`. This is where I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: Definitely a step in the right direction! However, I'm getting back 'cannot read property of `meta` undefined and `description` undefined' still.

Comment: what do you get when you console log the `selectedMovied` inside your select `onChange` method ?

Comment: I get `undefined` unfortunately

Comment: thats strange what you get when you console log `event.target.value` ?

Comment: I get the following with `console.log(event.target.value)` :

`[object Object]`

Comment: You should be getting the `id` for the console.log(event.target.value) when you select a movie .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235981/discussion-between-railsrabbit-and-shyam).

Comment: It was a data issue causing an error in the end, again thank you for your help.